# como leer variable de javascript en otro php

Tags: javascript

Buenas, estoy realizando un proyecto en php y quisiera saber como puede utilizar el valor de una variable que se encuentra dentro de un script en otra pagina php.

Este es el script:

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cbx_materia').on('change',function(){
          var id=$('#cbx_materia').val();
          document.getElementById("materia").value = id;
     });
});

</script>
```

Lo que deseo es usar la variable **id** seleccionada de un combobox en otra pagina por ejemplo reporte.php, como puedo pasar ese valor?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener un input tipo hidden sin valor asignado y cuando haces la selección en el select, le pones el valor seleccionado con javascript. Tal y como muestra el código:

```
<body>

<input type="hidden" name="materia" id="materia" value="">
</body>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cbx_materia').on('change',function(){
          var id=$('#cbx_materia').val();
          $("materia).val(id)
     });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar el método `POST` de `JQuery` para enviarla a `PHP` así

```
$.post( "reporte.php", {idComboBox: id});
```

y en `PHP` lo obtiene así;

```
$idJavascript = $_POST['idComboBox'];
```